# servlet doPut request.getParameter

Tags: jquery, servlets

I have an jquery ajax request

```
$('#updateUser').live( 'click', function() {
    var euserId = editeduserId; 
    var pname = $('#euname').val();
    var psurname = $('#eusurname').val();
    var plogin = $('#eulogin').val();
    var ppassword = $('#eupassword').val();
    var pemail = $('#euemail').val();
    var user = {name: pname, 
                surname: psurname, 
                login: plogin,
                password: ppassword,
                email: pemail};

    $.ajax({
        url: '/SimpleAjaxShit/UserController/' + euserId,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: user,
        success: function(data) {               
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data, response) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(response);
        } 
    });
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "close" );
});
```

and doPut method in servlet, which serves ajax request

```
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    String name = request.getParameter("name"); //Null
    String surname = request.getParameter("surname"); //Null
    String login = request.getParameter("login"); //Null
    String password = request.getParameter("password"); //Null
    String email = request.getParameter("email"); //Null        
}
```

I can see me params in headers,
but request.getParameter("name") and others return Null

Answer (score 0):

> I can see me params in headers

If you are seeing your parameters in the headers of the HTTP request, then you should use `request.getHeader()` method to fetch the values from the headers.

`request.getParameter()` is typically used to fetch the values from the parameters in your query string.